# Create arraylist from given array input

Tags: javascript, arrays

here is array data

```
 {"start":"20160530T164500",
  "end":"20160530T173000",
 "rule":"FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO,WE",
 "summary":"Meeting on Monday/wed"}
```

I have to read the rule param and based on by day, would need to create rows as below

for example, it has MO,WE so would need 2 array rows as below

```
{"day":"MO","start":"20160530T164500","end":"20160530T173000","rule":"FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO,WE","summary":"Meeting on Monday/wed"}
{"day":"WE","start":"20160530T164500","end":"20160530T173000","rule":"FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO,WE","summary":"Meeting on Monday/wed"}
```

experts in javascript/array...any suggestions please...

Comment: so you want loop over the structure , then for every you print the the data?

Comment: Yes..something like that...once i get BYDAY=MO,TU,WE.... it has to create array based on that BYDAY VALUES       ..here it will be 3 rows...                                                                 {"day":"MO","start":"20160530T164500","end":"20160530T173000","rule":"FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO,WE","summary":"Meeting on Monday/wed"}{"day":"TU","start":"20160530T164500","end":"20160530T173000","rule":"FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,","summary":"Meeting on Monday/wed"}
{"day":"WE","start":"20160530T164500","end":"20160530T173000","rule":"FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO,WE","summary":"Meeting on Monday/wed"}

Comment: put that code in style, its hard to read were not machines.

Comment: ya i do see that...but comment section doesnt allow me to format.
see if this helps you to understand

Comment: var array1={"start":"20160530T164500","end":"20160530T173000","rule":"FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO,WE","summary":"Meeting"}
 into (based on byday param values
 var array1={"day":"MO","start":"20160530T164500","end":"20160530T173000","rule":"FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO,WE","summary":"Meeting"}
{"day":"WE","start":"20160530T164500","end":"20160530T173000","rule":"FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO,WE","summary":"Meeting"}

Answer (score 1):

```
let data = {"start":"20160530T164500","end":"20160530T173000","rule":"FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO,WE","summary":"Meeting on Monday/wed"};

let result = data['rule'];

let ans = result.split("=");
```

that should contain the `WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO,WE` WEEKLY; and BYDAY=MO,WE

Comment: use var instead , sorry i am using es6 syntax

Comment: Thanks for that..I did applied var in js..but not sure where my array loop is missing... can you please check and assist?
var temprule="MO,WE";
    var rulest =[];
    rulest=temprule.split(',');
     console.log("TTTTT rulest", rulest);    
    for(var j = 0; j < rulest.length; j++) {    
     var day=rulest[j];
             entry.day=day; 
             console.log(entry.day) // log shows MO and WE as per loop             
             jsondata.push(entry);  // but jsondata has 2 entreies with day WE  }       
 incorrect o/p ->[{day=WE},day=WE}]  expected--> [{day=MO},day=WE}]